# apache benchmark server performance test unreasonable result

Tags: testing, server, load, benchmarking, apachebench

I am testing the general performance of my home server using apache benchmark. However, when I test the server with 1 user and 10000 requests the reported requests per second is around 250 (on average) all the time but when I do the test with 10 users and 10000 requests then it reports that the requests per second is around 1134. I have tested these two scenarios multiple times and get this unreasonable result. What I am thinking is, why does it jump from approximately 200 req/sec to 1134 req/sec. Shouldn't the first test also give the same or close result?  Both tests send more than 1000 requests.

```
ab -c 1 -n 1000 http://168.192.54.8/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1706008 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 168.192.54.8 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.29
Server Hostname:        168.192.54.8
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        9381 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   3.954 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      9654000 bytes
HTML transferred:       9381000 bytes
Requests per second:    252.92 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3.954 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       3.954 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2384.49 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   0.3      1       2
Processing:     2    3   0.6      3       7
Waiting:        1    2   0.5      2       5
Total:          2    4   0.7      4       9

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      4
  66%      4
  75%      4
  80%      4
  90%      5
  95%      5
  98%      6
  99%      6
 100%      9 (longest request)
```

```
ab -c 25 -n 10000 http://168.192.54.8/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1706008 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 168.192.54.8 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.29
Server Hostname:        168.192.54.8
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        9381 bytes

Concurrency Level:      25
Time taken for tests:   8.788 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      96540000 bytes
HTML transferred:       93810000 bytes
Requests per second:    1137.91 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       21.970 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.879 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          10727.90 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    4  14.7      3    1037
Processing:     3   18   4.9     19      44
Waiting:        2    6   2.9      5      30
Total:          5   22  15.4     23    1050

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     23
  66%     24
  75%     24
  80%     25
  90%     27
  95%     29
  98%     32
  99%     35
 100%   1050 (longest request)
```

Comment: Does "users" mean (more?) parallelism in your test?  Does your CPU have 4 cores or more, so multiple parallel requests can keep them all busy?

Comment: According to apache documentation "Users or -c parameter" means concurrency Number of multiple requests to perform at a time. Default is one request at a time."  Yes, my CPU has 4 cores. I also think my CPU cores will be always busy regardless of the type of perfromance test I perform on the server.

Comment: Ok, then it shouldn't be surprising that throughput scales with parallelism.  You have a multi-core CPU, right?  It's not rare for modern systems to have better throughput than latency, and waiting for one request to finish before making another request botlenecks on latency, not throughput.